# The expected number of draws until four successive cards of the same suit appear

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, renewal-processes

This is question 3.24 from Stochastic Process, 2nd ed. by Sheldon Ross.

Draw cards one at a time, with replacement, from a standard deck of playing cards. Find the expected number of draws until four successive cards of the same suit appear.

I know if I want 4 successive cards of the same suit given the suit the expectation would just be $4^4+4^3+4^2+4$. But I don't know how to proceed if I am not given the suit.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Express the expected value in terms of itself in an equation by taking cases.

Answer (score 1):

We have the equalities:

- $\mu_{3}=1+\frac{3}{4}\mu_{1}$
- $\mu_{2}=1+\frac{3}{4}\mu_{1}+\frac{1}{4}\mu_{3}$
- $\mu_{1}=1+\frac{3}{4}\mu_{1}+\frac{1}{4}\mu_{2}$
- $\mu_{0}=1+\mu_{1}$

Here e.g. $\mu_2$ stands for the expectation under the extra condition that from the cards drawn already the last $2$ cards (and not more) are of the same suite.

Note that in that situation there is a probability of $\frac14$ that we arrive in the situation where the last $3$ cards drawn are of the same suite and  a probability of $\frac14$ that a card of another suite will be drawn so that we must start over again.

This consideration makes clear that $$\mu_2=\frac34(1+\mu_1)+\frac14(1+\mu_3)=1+\frac34\mu_1+\frac14\mu_3$$

To be found is $\mu_0$ and the equalities enable you to find it.

Comment: Although you get the same answer as I do, I can't figure out what you are doing. Could you explain a little better because I don't know what the $\mu_i$ variables mean.

Comment: @user5713492 Nice to hear that you have the same answer. I discern $4$ statuses and each of them is linked with an expectation. You are in status $0$ if you start and $\mu_0$ denotes the expectation of the number of draws needed to arrive for the first time in the situation where $4$ successive cards of the same suite have appeared. So that is the expectation we must find. You are in status $1$ if at least one card is drawn and where this card is not from the same suite as its precedor (if there is a preceder). The expectation linked is denoted as $\mu_1$ and differs from $\mu_0$.....

Comment: @user5713492....Notice e.g. that drawing $3$ cards can bring us to our goal already while in status $0$ at least $4$ cards are necessary. If at least $2$ cards are drawn and the last $2$ cards are of the same suite and the eventual precedor of these cards has a different suite then you are in status $2$. Et cetera.

Comment: OK, now I follow your method. But right off the bat you have $4$ equations in $4$ unknowns, so why the fifth equation? It seems to say that $$\frac14\mu_2=\frac14\mu_1+1$$ while the third equation says that $$\frac14\mu_2=\frac14\mu_1-1$$

Comment: @user5713492 What you call the fifth equation was presented as a part of an effort to explain things. I chose for clarification of the second equality. Unfortunately two typos were made that are now repaired. That must have been the source of some confusion (sorry). Indeed the four bullets in my answer are enough for finding a solution.

Comment: OK, that makes more sense.